# Raspberry Kernel Parameters

Tags: boot, kernel

I'm working on the `/boot/cmdline.txt`, and found the parameters : `vt.cur_default=1 vt.global_cursor_default=0`. Where I can get the full documentation about vt? does it have other parameters? Thank all!

Comment: This is not raspberry pi specific, but the kernel's command line parameters are documented [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html).